# Find top student from three test marks

Tags: code-golf

First save the following text into a file called `marks.csv`

```
Smith,6,9,24
Jones,9,12,20
Fred,5,9,20
```

Each line contains a students name and three marks they scored. Find the top student by simply summing the three marks and then output their name. In this case the output is:

```
Jones
```

I would like to see somebody beat my Python solution but any language will be allowed :) If anybody beats my Python solution I will accept their answer but for now I will just accept the shortest code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## K, 37

```
m[0;*>+/1_m:("SIII";",")0:`marks.csv]
```

Answer (score 2):

### Cat (5 characters)

```
Jones
```

You don't specify that the code has to work on other datasets as well ;-)

Save code in a file `FILE` and execute with:

```
cat FILE
```

Comment: Doesn't follow the requirement: `Find the top student by simply summing the three marks *and then* output their name`

Comment: Don't you see the part right before the word Jones? It does all the calculations.

Comment: *In this case* implies other input is possible. -1

Answer (score 2):

### *Mathematica*, 44

```
SortBy[Tr/@Import@"marks.csv",First][[-1,2]]
```

If I were allowed to save the data in *Mathematica*'s native format in a file named `z` I could use:

```
SortBy[Tr/@<<z,First][[-1,2]]
```

Comment: Your answer appears to be problematic. Try running: `Tr /@ Import@"marks.csv"`. I get `{"{6, 9, 24}" + "Smith", "{9, 12, 20}" + "Jones", "{5, 9, 20}" + "Fred"}` as output.

Comment: @David I think your file is in the wrong format.  It should contain exactly the text shown in the first code block in the question.

Comment: Would you kindly show me the exact code you are using for exporting the file in the first place.  Somehow, my integer lists are interpreted as strings.

Comment: @David I didn't `Export` the file; I used Notepad and pasted the text from the question into it.

Answer (score 2):

### Ruby 1.9 (<del>71</del> 62)

```ruby
$><<open('marks.csv').max_by{|l|eval l[/,.*/].tr ?,,?+}[/\w+/]
```

Answer (score 1):

**PHP, <s>103</s> 95**

I know PHP is not the best tool for this problem, however I would appreciate any tip to improve my answer :)

First version (103)

```
<?$h=fopen('marks.csv','r');for(;$f=fgetcsv($h);$m[$f[0]]=array_sum($f));echo array_search(max($m),$m);
```

Improved version, inspired by @Leigh's solution (95) - considering low error level:

```
<?$h=fopen('marks.csv',r);for(;$f=fgetcsv($h);$m[array_sum($f)]=$f[0]);ksort($m);echo end($m);
```

Easier to read version:

```
<?
$h=fopen('marks.csv',r);
for(; $f=fgetcsv($h); $m[$f[0]]=array_sum($f));
echo array_search(max($m),$m);
```

Thanks

Comment: I was just about to post a new solution based on yours ;) - Except I had moved the fopen into the first part of the for loop. FYI I started the results array the same as yours, with arsort + key. Then I reversed the results and used ksort + end. Every little helps :)

Answer (score 1):

### PHP, <s>97</s> 93

Original

```
foreach(file('marks.csv')as$l){$x=str_getcsv($l);$r[array_sum($x)]=$x[0];}ksort($r);echo end($r);
```

Inspired by milo5b

```
for($f=fopen('marks.csv','r');$l=fgetcsv($f);)$r[array_sum($l)]=$l[0];ksort($r);echo end($r);
```

And how to run without tags.

`cat golf.php | php -a`

Comment: You would also need starting <? php tag. And by the way, you inspired an improvement to my solution, thanks eheh +1

Comment: Don't need the tags, and thanks to you too ;)

Comment: eheh great I did not know this. I will not edit my solution further or we'll end up with exactly the same code!

Comment: btw i think you forgot to take off the string quotes around 'r' in fopen

Comment: I'll let you keep that one, or we'll end up with the same code ;)

Comment: You should add two bytes for the '-a' switch :P

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica <strike>59</strike> <strike>49</strike> 53 chars

```
Sort[{Tr@Rest@#, #[[1]]} & /@ Import@"marks.csv"][[-1, 2]]
```

Because csv is a subject to various interpretations, I'm including the exact file contents of o.csv:

```
{{"Smith", 6, 9, 24}, {"Jones", 9, 12, 20}, {"Fred", 5, 9, 20}}
```

Comment: I missed the filename requirement, which is now taken into account.

Comment: fix taken into account ;-) +1

Comment: @Mr.Wizard It turns out that `%` will work as the file name, provided that it is executed right after exporting the file.

Comment: I like your ambition, but honestly I don't think that's fair: the export becomes part of your program.

Comment: I rolled back to an earlier version for another reason. I seem to have been getting the right answer for the wrong reason.

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <del>146</del> <del>134</del> 133 bytes

(feedback welcome)

```javascript
s=a=>eval(a.split`,`.slice`1`.join`+`);_=>(""+require("fs").readFileSync("marks.csv")).split`
`.sort((a,b)=>s(b)-s(a))[0].split`,`[0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY2xDoIwFEV3PoPpvVAaIGpiSBkdXB2NsQUaLZaW9DX8fkVj3E5yc86d1KpoCGaJpfOjTrMKLxLyMpv4ZAd2ZM0uO3unacO6YU2VnYIe2f6zVLJNJJTo9KosKE6LNVEyycmaQcta8skbJwuJ7eAdeau59Q@Au@ggz4vvFf6sbLN8iACK9Sg6gh5LAoV4rW7/8MYIiCm9AQ)

Answer (score 0):

### Python, 82

```
print max((sum(eval(m)),n)for n,m in(l.split(',',1)for l in open("marks.csv")))[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Awk, 64**

```
$ awk -F, '{s=$2+$3+$4;if(s>m){m=s;n=$1}}END{print n}' marks.csv
```

Comment: `{s=$2+$3+$4}s>m{m=s;n=$1}END{print n}` is shorter - 30 chars

Answer (score 0):

### R, 58

```
j=read.csv("marks.csv",F);j[which.max(rowSums(j[,2:4])),1]
```

Alternatively (62 characters):

```
j=read.csv("marks.csv",F);j[which.max(apply(j[,2:4],1,sum)),1]
```

Answer (score 0):

## k (47 chars)

Allows for ties

```
(*x)'&(|/i)=i:+/'+:1_x:("SIII";",")0:`marks.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be orthodox and first of it kind on Code golf. Below will work find under circumstances where CSV file - been imported into as a table ( External Table) on Oracle.

M := Marks.csv Table
a-d := CSV Fields

PLSQL **60** Characters

```
SELECT a,max(b+c+d) FROM M WHERE ROWNUM<=1 GROUP BY a,b,c,d;
```

Answer (score 0):

***C#*** Two different versions

***Version:1 245*** Characters

```
using System;using System.Linq;namespace X{class Y{static void Main(){Console.Write((from l in System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("m.csv")let x =l.Split(',')select new{f=x[0],a=x.Skip(1).Sum(Z=>Int32.Parse(Z))}).OrderByDescending(p=>p.a).First().f);}}}
```

***Version:2 214*** Characters

```
using System;using System.Linq;namespace X{class Y{static void Main(){Console.Write(System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("m.csv").OrderByDescending(z=>z.Split(',').Skip(1).Sum(y=>Int32.Parse(y))).First().Split(',')[0]);}}}
```